# Trigonometry equation. Not sure about solution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The equation goes as follows: 
$$\sin x +\cos x = 1 + \sin x \cos x$$

and here is how I solved it:

$$(\sin x+\cos x)^2=(1+\sin x\cos x)^2$$
$$\sin^2x+2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x=1+2\sin x\cos x+2\sin^2x\cos^2x$$
$$2\sin^2x\cos^2x=0$$

$$ \cos x=0; \sin x=0$$
$$x_1=\pi/2 +k\pi$$
$$x_2=k\pi$$

Where did it go wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you get a $2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$?  Shouldn't the coefficient be $1$?

Comment: Why do you believe that you made a mistake?  Make sure to plug in your answers into the original expression because squaring may have introduced extra solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Your work is correct, but incomplete. You have to verifiy the solutions because squaring you can introduce improper solutions and in your case these are the solutions for $k$ odd.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to solve this is just to factor everything like this:

$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(x)-1=(\sin(x)-1)(\cos(x)-1)=0$$
So you can see immediatly that you have solutions when $\cos(x)=1$ or $\sin(x)=1$, thus $x=2k\pi$ or $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

Comment: One quibble:  $\sin x + \cos x - \sin x\cos x - 1 = (\sin x - 1)(1 - \cos x)$.

Answer (score 0):

On your second line, the third term on the right hand side shouldn't have a 2 in front of it.

When you square a binomial, you get the general form $$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$$

So in your case $$(1 + \sin(x)\cos(x))^2 = 1 + 2\sin(x)\cos(x) + \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$$

From there, you should be able to solve for x quite easily

Comment: This is a mistake in the OP's solution, but observe that it doesn't change the answer that the OP developed.

Comment: I wish my mistakes had a similar null effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in calculating $(A+B)^2=A^2+2AB+B^2$ (though this mistake does not affect the result.)

In addition to this, $\cos x=0\ \text{or}\ \sin x=0$ is just a necessary condition. Because you squared the both sides, you need to check if they are sufficient. (For example, $x=3\pi/2$ is not a solution.)

Comment: You are right that a mistake was made. However, the mistake did not affect the result since its effect was coming up with $2f(x) = 0$ instead of the correct $f(x) = 0$. Good catch though.

Comment: @martycohen: You are right. When I first wrote my answer, I wrote only the second paragraph. Then, I began to think that adding the first paragraph may be better :) (maybe I should have mentioned that that mistake does not affect the result. so edited)